# How to build a MVC project programmatically

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, msbuild

I need to build a mvc project programmatically, for my requirements i write the code snippet as follows

```
var logger = new BuildILogger();

var projectName = templateLocation + @"\sampleProj.csproj";

 var project = new ProjectCollection();
 var parameters = new BuildParameters(project);
 parameters.DetailedSummary = true;
 parameters.Loggers = new List<ILogger>() { logger };

var buildRequestData = new BuildRequestData(projectName, properties, null, new string[] { "Build" }, null);

var result = BuildManager.DefaultBuildManager.Build(parameters,buildRequestData);
```

But i cannot able to build the mvc project.

result.OverallResult = Failure always

Where i commit my mistake. Figure it out my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is fine. Examine the MSBuild engine's output at the following successive levels of detail as necessary, until you identify the cause of the failure:

- Dump `result.Exception`.
- Go to the output from `logger` (its location should be specified in your `BuildILogger` class).
- Set `BuildILogger.Verbosity` to `BuildILogger.Detailed`, execute your code again and go back to the output from `logger`.
- Set `BuildILogger.Verbosity` to `BuildILogger.Diagnostic`, execute your code again and go back to the output from `logger`.